# Detecting SQL strings

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I have been trying to figure out a regex for matching complete strings in SQL, from a .sql file (including escaped single quotes), and the ones I've come up with either don't capture enough of the string or result in a StackOverflow exception (I suspect from the possible combinations of `''|[^']`.

The regex I was trying to build was something along the lines of

`(?<!')'(''|[^'])*'(?!')`

I want there to be a `'` starting and ending the string, with any number of *pairs* of `'` and non single '`' characters between.

One solution I considered is to first replace pairs of `'` with a different character and then simply look for anything between single `'`, but is there way to configure my regex to do this (and actually run).

Comment: I just tried your regex on `-'This is a string. It''s single quoted!!!'''-`, and it returned the correct substring nigh-instantly.

Comment: Note however that your lookahead/lookbehind have no practical effect, since the search starts at the beginning of the string, and the middle part is greedy.

Comment: Yes, it works for single instances and test cases, but I'm working with tens/hundreds of thousands of lines of SQL code, some which are huge chunks of dynamic SQL. Using this regex results a StackOverflow error. I wanted to know if there was an alternative that didn't utilize `''|[^']`, as that is what I'm suspecting is causing it.

Comment: That section of the regex is pretty safe - it will never cause any more than a linear amount of backtracking, since there's no character that is valid on both sides.  Also, the stack usage won't persist over many records.  I would look for some other part of your code to accuse of causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: I used a possessive quantifier. This regex will detect a SQL string (with possible escaped quotes):

`'([']{2}|[^'])*+'(?!')`